# Understanding the different #define Declarations

Tags: c, macros

I have a code base which uses #define in a different way then I am accustomed to.

I know that, for example, `#define a 5` will replace variable a with 5 in the code.

But what would this mean:

```
'#define MSG_FLAG 5, REG, MSGCLR'
```

I tried doing it in a simple code and compiling it. It takes the last value (like the third argument as MSGCLR).

Comment: `MSG_FLAG` is simply replaced by `5, REG, MSGCLR` everywhere. From there it's the *comma operator* what you are interested in.

Comment: BTW.. is everyone seeing these `'` around the code block? They are not there when trying to edit..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't think it is a comma *operator*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala *"It takes the last value"* thing

Comment: @EugeneSh. ... goes into arguments or an initialization list => not a comma operator.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The use case is not described in the question, but the symptom I quoted is pointing to the operator use-case.

Comment: @EugeneSh. ah yes, I read incorrectly. But its intended use is not as such.

Answer (score 5):

Preprocessing is largely just string replacement that happens before the "real" compilation starts. So we don't have any idea of what a variable is at this point.

The commas here are not any special syntax. This will cause any appearance of `MSG_FLAG` in the code to be replaced by `5, REG, MSGCLR`

Most compilers have a flag that will *just* run the preprocessor, so you can see for yourself. On gcc, this is -E.

So to verify this, we can have some nonsense source:

```
#define MSG_FLAG 5, REG, MSGCLR

MSG_FLAG
```

Compile with `gcc -E test.c`

And the output is:

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.c"


5, REG, MSGCLR
```

Comment: The compiler will not see `MSG_FLAG.` The compiler will see `5, REG, MSGCLR` instead.

Comment: it takes the last initializer

Comment: @ani what takes it?

Comment: @immibis Compiler?

Comment: @ani Could you show how this gets used in the code? Maybe that will clear things up